# Swift: how to stop exposing the delegate methods

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, swift-extensions

**WorkAround:**

I am creating a utility class let's say `BLEScanManager`, which is responsible to scan nearby BLE devices. The only job of the utility class is to scan BLE devices and make a list of it.

The other classes can create an object of this `BLEScanManager` and get an array of BLE devices, like `[Bluetooth]` (here `Bluetooth` is a custom modal class).

Now to scan BLE devices, I have created the extension of `BLEScanManager` in the same class and override its delegate methods like below:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

protocol BLEScanDelegate {
   func reloadDeviceList()
}

internal class BLEScanManager: NSObject {

    private var centralManager: CBCentralManager?
    var devices : [Bluetooth] = []
    var delegate: BLEScanDelegate?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: .main)
    }

    // MARK:- Custom methods
    func isScanning() -> Bool {
        return centralManager?.isScanning ?? false
    }

    func stopScanning() {
        centralManager?.stopScan()
    }

    func startScanning() {
        devices.removeAll()
        let options: [String: Any] = [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:
            NSNumber(value: false)]
        centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: options)
    }
}

extension BLEScanManager : CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch central.state {
            case .unknown:      print("central.state is .unknown")
            case .resetting:    print("central.state is .resetting")
            case .unsupported:  print("central.state is .unsupported")
            case .unauthorized: print("central.state is .unauthorized")
            case .poweredOff:   print("central.state is .poweredOff")
            case .poweredOn:    print("central.state is .poweredOn")
                                self.startScanning()
            @unknown default:   fatalError("unknow state")
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print("Discovered \(peripheral)")
        var bluetooth = Bluetooth()
        bluetooth.name = peripheral.name
        bluetooth.identifier = peripheral.identifier.uuidString
        bluetooth.state = peripheral.state.rawValue
        bluetooth.advertisementData = advertisementData
        let power = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataTxPowerLevelKey] as? Double
        let value: Double = pow(10, ((power ?? 0 - Double(truncating: RSSI))/20))
        bluetooth.signalStrength = String(describing: value.round)

        // Do not add duplicate device
        let fitlerArray : [Bluetooth] = devices.filter { $0.identifier ==  bluetooth.identifier}
        if fitlerArray.count == 0 {
            devices.append(bluetooth)
        }
        self.delegate?.reloadDeviceList()
    }
}
```

The thing here is these methods are exposed in the other classes too.

For example:

I have created an object of `BLEScanManager` in other class `BLEListViewController` to show a list of BLE device in `UITableView`.

```
class BLEListViewController: UITableViewController {
     var scanManager: BLEScanManager!
}
```

I can access `CBCentralManagerDelegate` delegate methods in `BLEListViewController` class using an object `scanManager`.

Like below,

```
self.scanManager.centralManager?(<#T##central: CBCentralManager##CBCentralManager#>, didConnect: <#T##CBPeripheral#>)
```

This should expose the internal utility delegate methods to the outside world.

Question is how to stop exposing these delegates?

Please note that, if I use `internal` keyword it only hides that specific method. But it still allows accessing all other `CBCentralManagerDelegate` methods.

Comment: Not sure if it works but have you tried `private extension BLEScanManager : CBCentralManagerDelegate`?

Comment: I have previously used [SwiftyBluetooth Library](https://github.com/jordanebelanger/SwiftyBluetooth) which allowed me to change the core bluetooth using delegate methods to Closure based methods. Perhaps this can help you

Comment: @Tj3n: Yes I tried with it, it gives me an error: 'private' modifier cannot be used with extensions that declare protocol conformances

Comment: @chirag90: Thanks, let me check that too.

Comment: To make it more clear, I have added all the code of utility class

Answer (score 3):

There’s nothing you can do about this. It is a problem with all optional protocol methods. The trouble is that optional protocol methods are an Objective C feature. You cannot hide such a method as private, because now Objective C cannot see it and so the method will never be discovered and called. It’s a flaw in the way Swift interfaces with Objective C. You just have to live with it.

Comment: I was wondering if we can do so to make it. But I guess thats not possible. Thanks for the details explanation, let's hope we can get a way in future.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do, is to hide behind a protocol - see the following example.

```
protocol Exposed {
 func run()
}

struct Bluetooth {
 func hidden() {
  print("This method is hidden - ish")
 }
}

extension Bluetooth: Exposed {
 func run() {
  print("this method is exposed")
 }
}

struct BluetoothScanManager {
 static func scan() -> [Exposed] {
  return [Bluetooth(), Bluetooth()]
 }
}
```

Now, when you run `BluetoothScanManager` you will get a list of exposed only with the `run()` method available, but behind the code it is a `Bluetooth`

```
for exposed in BluetoothScanManager.scan() {
 exposed.run()
 exposed.hidden() // not possible
}
```

Comment: Very appreciated your help, but the thing is the delegates are `CBCentralManagerDelegate` which is not controlled by us. Your answer will work if we are using custom delegate methods. But how we can apply above policy to `CBCentralManagerDelegate` methods?

Comment: @Kampai may be use an internal class which confirms to CBCentralManagerDelegate.

Comment: @Kampai when the class is internal make the instance private also. when it's access is private it shouldn't be visible/accessible to outside world

Comment: Maybe I have gotten the wrong idea of your problem. But you can still hide behind an interface, and simply dont allow the creation of BLEScanManager, but let it have a method like:

```
struct BLEScanManager {
  static func createManager() -> Exposed {
    return BLEScanManager()
  }
  private init() {}
}
extension BLEScanManager: Exposed { ... }

Comment: @magnuskahr: Can you please edit your answer and provide these comments details in the answer, so that I can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Your only way to do this (which also is the correct way in my opinion) is to create a new private object inside the `BLEScanManager` class that implements the `CBCentralManagerDelegate`.

Than you can pass this object to the `CBCentralManager` init method.

If you then need to comunicate from this object to the `BLEScanManager` you can simply use another delegate with a private protocol so it doesn't show those methods outside of the class.

It would look something like this:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

protocol BLEScanDelegate {
   func reloadDeviceList()
}



internal class BLEScanManager: NSObject {

    private var centralManager: CBCentralManager?
    var devices : [Bluetooth] = []
    var delegate: BLEScanDelegate?
    let centralManagerDelegate = MyCentralManagerDelegateImplementation()
    override init() {
        super.init()
        centralManagerDelegate.delegate = self
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: centralManagerDelegate, queue: .main)
    }

    // MARK:- Custom methods
    func isScanning() -> Bool {
        return centralManager?.isScanning ?? false
    }

    func stopScanning() {
        centralManager?.stopScan()
    }

    func startScanning() {
        devices.removeAll()
        let options: [String: Any] = [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:
            NSNumber(value: false)]
        centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: options)
    }
}

private extension BLEScanManager: CentralManagerEventsDelegate {
    func didUpdateState(){
        // Here goes the switch with the startScanning
    }


    func didDiscoverPeripheral(...) {
        // Here goes the logic on new peripheral and the call on self.delegate?.reloadDeviceList
    }

}

internal protocol CentralManagerEventsDelegate: class {
    func didUpdateState()
    func didDiscoverPeripheral(...)
}

internal class MyCentralManagerDelegateImplementation: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {

    weak var delegate: CentralManagerEventsDelegate?

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        self.delegate?.didUpdateState()
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        self.delegate?.didDiscoverPeripheral(actualParams)
    }
}
```